# KeyEvents not taking space after the text in android

Tags: android, react-native, keyevent

I am using react-native-keyevent to capture input events through the android app. I'm trying to capture `ASDERFF|ERRTO|     |` using events. I'm able to get only `ASDERFF|ERRTO|` remaining spaces and the pipe is not reading. Space is not working out the events. Please let me know to accept spaces. I tried using

```
adb shell input text "some%stext"
```

output: "some text"

```
adb shell input text "some text"
```

output: "some"

In MainActivity.java

```
//adb shell input text "some text"
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  Log.d("DEBUG", "onKeyUp event: "+event.toString()); 
  KeyEventModule.getInstance().onKeyUpEvent(keyCode, event);
  return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Debug output for *`adb shell input text "some text"`*

```
KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_S, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, repeatCount=0, eventTime=29540713, downTime=29540713, deviceId=-1, source=0x101, displayId=-1 }
KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_O, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, repeatCount=0, eventTime=29540713, downTime=29540713, deviceId=-1, source=0x101, displayId=-1 }
KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_M, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, repeatCount=0, eventTime=29540713, downTime=29540713, deviceId=-1, source=0x101, displayId=-1 }
KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_E, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, repeatCount=0, eventTime=29540713, downTime=29540713, deviceId=-1, source=0x101, displayId=-1 }
```

Versions:
**ReactNative: 0.63.2**
**react-native-keyevent: 0.2.8**

Comment: Please paste the actual code you're using in your listener event in RN application. Are you tracking down `pressedKey` or `keyCode` since that might affect on the output?

Comment: @SamuliHakoniemi `onKeyUp` method Space event and the characters after Space is not getting called.